# Mercurial, ignore only object files for which the source is there

Tags: mercurial, binary, hgignore

I have quite a few objects (.o) files in my (future) Mercurial repository.  I have the source for most of them, but some were downloaded / provided by collaborators and I don't have the sources.  Of course, versioning binary files is bad, but I'd like to do that for the few files for which I don't have the sources (given that they will rarely, if ever, be modified, and that on the other hand I cannot regenerate them myself).

Assuming that I have a simple way of determining where .c corresponding to a .o is if it exists (e.g. always in the same folder), is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely add `*.o` files to your `.hgignore`, and then manually `hg add` specific `*.o` files to the repository for tracking. Any automatic adding (such as `hg addremove`, or `hg add` without an argument) will still ignore `*.o` files, but you can manually add anything ignored and it *will* be tracked.

Comment: This is the best way to do it.  Ignore broadly and override with add

Comment: Sure, that's easy to do... but is there no way to automate this given that I have a simple rule to determine what to keep?

Comment: If there are a lot of `.o` files you need to track, I would add `*.o` to `.hgignore` and then write a script to iterate through `*.o` files and call `hg add` on the ones that don't have matching `.c` file. After the `.o` files you want to track are added, there is nothing else to automate.